# dropdown list on button click compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-dropdownmenu

How to create a dropdown menu items on a button click. In Jetpack compose?

Like here but for buttons :

```
      DropdownMenu(
            expanded = expanded,
            onDismissRequest = { expanded = false },
            toggle = iconButton,
            dropdownOffset = Position(24.dp, 0.dp),
            toggleModifier = modifier
        ) {
            options.forEach {
                DropdownMenuItem(onClick = {}) {
                    Text(it)
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: No idea what you want to achieve, but the parameter toggle can be used for anything you want. So if you want a regular button and not an icon button just replace it with ``toggle = {Button(onClick={setExpanded(!expanded)}){Text("Open Dropdown")}}``. I hope this helped you.

Answer (score 3):

The previous answer is correct, but the key part is missing. Both, **DropdownMenu** and the **button** that opens it suppose to be wrapped in **Box**. Only this way the opening button will be used as an **anchor** for the menu.
This is my version:

```
@Composable
fun DropdownMenu(
    colorSelected: Color = scColors.primary,
    colorBackground: Color = scColors.onSurface,
    expanded: Boolean,
    selectedIndex: Int,
    items: List<String>,
    onSelect: (Int) -> Unit,
    onDismissRequest: () -> Unit,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    Box {
        content()
        DropdownMenu(
            expanded = expanded,
            onDismissRequest = onDismissRequest,
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(300.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(
                    color = colorBackground,
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp)
                )
        ) {
            items.forEachIndexed { index, s ->
                if (selectedIndex == index) {
                    DropdownMenuItem(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .background(
                                color = colorSelected,
                                shape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp)
                            ),
                        onClick = { onSelect(index) }
                    ) {
                        Text(
                            text = s,
                            color = Color.Black,
                            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                        )
                    }
                } else {
                    DropdownMenuItem(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                        onClick = { onSelect(index) }
                    ) {
                        Text(
                            text = s,
                            color = Color.DarkGray,
                            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And, then a DropdownMenu accepts the opening anchor button as a content:

```
val items = listOf(
    "English",
    "Russian",
    "Spanish",
    "French",
    "German",
    "Hebrew"
)

@Preview
@Composable
fun TestDropdownMenu() {
    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    var selectedIndex by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    val buttonTitle = items[selectedIndex]
    DropdownMenu(
        colorSelected = scColors.onSurface,
        colorBackground = scColors.primary,
        expanded = expanded,
        selectedIndex = selectedIndex,
        items = items,
        onSelect = { index ->
            selectedIndex = index
            expanded = false
        },
        onDismissRequest = {
            expanded = false
        }) {

        Button(
            onClick = {
                expanded = true
            }
        ) {
            Text(
                text = buttonTitle,
                color = Color.Black,
                maxLines = 1,
                overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like:

```
   var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

   Button(onClick = { expanded = true }){
        Text ("...")
    }
    DropdownMenu(
        expanded = expanded,
        onDismissRequest = { expanded = false },
        //....
    ) {
        items.forEachIndexed { index, s ->
            //....
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a dropdown list in compose by using this

list : list you want to show

label : label is the hint to show in the textview

default : to set default value in textview

validateInput = you can validate the input by changing the validateInput state to true on the button clicked and handle it accordingly

```
fun dropdownList(
list: List<String>,
label: String,
defaultValue: String = "",
validateInput: Boolean
): String {

var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
var selectedText by remember { mutableStateOf(defaultValue) }
var textFieldSize by remember { mutableStateOf(Size.Zero) }
var isError by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

if (validateInput && selectedText.isEmpty())
    isError = true

val icon = if (expanded)
    Icons.Filled.ArrowDropUp
else
    Icons.Filled.ArrowDropDown


Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 2.dp, top = 2.dp)) {
    OutlinedTextField(
        value = selectedText,
        onValueChange = {
            selectedText = it
        },
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .onGloballyPositioned { coordinates ->
                textFieldSize = coordinates.size.toSize()
            },
        label = { Text(label) },
        trailingIcon = {
            Icon(icon, "contentDescription",
                Modifier.clickable { expanded = !expanded })
        },
        isError = isError
    )
    DropdownMenu(
        expanded = expanded,
        onDismissRequest = { expanded = false },
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(with(LocalDensity.current) { textFieldSize.width.toDp() })
    ) {
        list.forEach { label ->
            DropdownMenuItem(onClick = {
                selectedText = label
                expanded = false
            }) {
                Text(text = label)
            }
        }
    }
    if (isError) {
        Text(
            text = "$label can't be empty",
            color = Color.Red,
            textAlign = TextAlign.End,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
        )
    }
}
return selectedText
}
```

Github gist link [DropdownList.kt](https://gist.github.com/Hiteshpatel10/8cf4d4f7037ac5d79bdf6ce55527e042)